# Use of "palpite" in Brazilian Portuguese before 1900

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem, substantivos

In Spanish we have the word [*pálpito* (RAE)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RbMtQuf), with the same meaning as the word [*palpite* (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/palpite) in Portuguese:

> 2. [Figurado] Conhecimento intuitivo. = INTUIÇÃO, PRESSENTIMENTO, SUPOSIÇÃO

Some authors claim that the Spanish word comes indeed from the Portuguese one. [I have found](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27168/12637) texts in Argentinian press from 1900 that make use of *pálpito*. And in countries like Uruguay and Paraguay (half-way between Brazil and Argentina) the word is spelled *pálpite* or even *palpite*, same as Portuguese, though I have found no texts from these countries that use the word before 1900.

Nonetheless, what I want to know is how old is the Portuguese word *palpite* with the referred meaning? Was it used in Brazil before 1900?

Comment: Charlie, let me know if you'd like an English translation of the quotes in Portuguese in my answer.

Comment: @Jacinto thank you very much for your offer, it's very kind of you. Spanish and Portuguese are very much alike and besides I have get used to read texts in Spanish from the XV century and before, when both languages were even closer, so I understand your quotes. No problem. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### English (Portuguese below)

Yes, ***palpite*** meant ‘hunch’ before 1900 already, both in Brazil and Portugal. The first known use indicated in Dicionário Houaiss (Lisbon, 2002)―my first port of call for these type of enquiries―is the entry in the 1878 Moraes Silva dictionary (original spelling, rather different from the current one, in all quotes):

> **Palpite**, s. m. t. pop. Inspiração que sobrevem ao espirito para o mover a escolher ou fazer, sem motivo algum, alguma cousa de preferencia a outras.
> [Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, 7º edição, tomo II, Lisboa, 1878, p. 400.](http://www.docvirt.com/docreader.net/DocReader.aspx?bib=BibObPub&pasta=Diccionario%20da%20Lingua%20Portugueza%20-%206%C2%AA%20edicao,%20Tomo%20I,%20A-E&pesq=)

Naturally we find this use earlier. The earliest example I could find is from 1848, precisely in Brazil (my boldface in all quotes below):

> —Entaõ temos d’escolher entre a *roleta* e a *banca*… qual quereis?
> —Tanto sei d’um como d’outro.
> —Isso naõ obsta, meu caro. A roleta e a banca são jogos d’igual merecimento e inventados ambos para ignorantes da vossa especie… Não haveis de ser vós o que haveis de jogar, incumbir-se-ha disso o banqueiro. **Eia, disei a vossa opinião, segui o vosso palpite.**
> [Paulo Feval, *O Mendigo Negro*, translated by A. Rego, “natural do Maranhão,”  Maranhão, 1848, p. 116.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wRooAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA116&dq=%22segui%20o%20vosso%20palpite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs24im9I3dAhXOqYMKHapcChwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22segui%20o%20vosso%20palpite%22&f=false)

The 1878 dictionary says this use is informal, but we find it in 1874 in Brazil in a formal speech in a respectable institution:

> […] mas perguntará o orador a razão que levou o signatario do relatorio a considerar essas estimativas como mais dignas de confiança, foi **palpite** ou considerações e respeito aos autores ou autor das mesmas?
> [*Revista  do Instituto Polytechnico Brasileiro*, tomo III, Rio de Janeiro, 1874, p. 27.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9cg8AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=palpite&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgv288o3dAhUMY6wKHZGWDkkQ6AEIhwEwDg#v=onepage&q=palpite&f=false)

We find this use in Portugal too in [this 1861 magazine](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1L7_uP-EcKgC&pg=RA2-PA43&dq=palpite&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgv288o3dAhUMY6wKHZGWDkkQ6AEIrwEwFA#v=onepage&q=palpite&f=false) and in 1865 by the pen of a famous writer:

> —É muita delicadeza da parte de v. ex.ª, disse Iphigenia.
> —Oh, minha senhora!... tartamudeou o morgado da Agra, offerencendo-lhe o braço.
> —Parece, tornou ella quando iam subindo, que **o meu palpite não me enganou**…
> —O palpite de v. ex.ª
> —Sim… eu contava com um cavalheiro no rigor da palavra… Delicadeza egual ao talento, qualidades que raras vezes se conformam.
> [Camillo Castelo Branco, *A queda d’um anjo*, [1º edição 1865], Lisboa, 1873, p. 204.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=TMUNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA204&dq=palpite&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgv288o3dAhUMY6wKHZGWDkkQ6AEIjgEwDw#v=onepage&q=palpite&f=false)

---

### Portuguese

Sim, ***palpite*** já significava ‘pressentimento’ no século XIX, quer no Brasil quer em Portugal. O uso mais antigo do termo indicado no Dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002)―o melhor que eu conheço para este tipo de coisas―é o verbete no dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1878 (grafia original em todas as citações):

> **Palpite**, s. m. t. pop. Inspiração que sobrevem ao espirito para o mover a escolher ou fazer, sem motivo algum, alguma cousa de preferencia a outras.
> [Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, 7º edição, tomo II, Lisboa, 1878, p. 400.](http://www.docvirt.com/docreader.net/DocReader.aspx?bib=BibObPub&pasta=Diccionario%20da%20Lingua%20Portugueza%20-%206%C2%AA%20edicao,%20Tomo%20I,%20A-E&pesq=)

Naturalmente a palavra já se usava antes. A ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei é de 1848, e vem precisamente do Brasil (negrito meu em todas as citações seguintes):

> —Entaõ temos d’escolher entre a *roleta* e a *banca*… qual quereis?
> —Tanto sei d’um como d’outro.
> —Isso naõ obsta, meu caro. A roleta e a banca são jogos d’igual merecimento e inventados ambos para ignorantes da vossa especie… Não haveis de ser vós o que haveis de jogar, incumbir-se-ha disso o banqueiro. **Eia, disei a vossa opinião, segui o vosso palpite.**
> [Paulo Feval, *O Mendigo Negro*, traduzido por A. Rego, natural do Maranhão, Maranhão, 1848, p. 116.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wRooAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA116&dq=%22segui%20o%20vosso%20palpite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs24im9I3dAhXOqYMKHapcChwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22segui%20o%20vosso%20palpite%22&f=false)

O dicionário Moraes Silva qualifica este uso como popular, mas em 1874 já o encontramos, também no Brasil, em discursos cuidados em instituições respeitáveis:

> […] mas perguntará o orador a razão que levou o signatario do relatorio a considerar essas estimativas como mais dignas de confiança, foi **palpite** ou considerações e respeito aos autores ou autor das mesmas?
> [*Revista  do Instituto Polytechnico Brasileiro*, tomo III, Rio de Janeiro, 1874, p. 27.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9cg8AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=palpite&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgv288o3dAhUMY6wKHZGWDkkQ6AEIhwEwDg#v=onepage&q=palpite&f=false)

Também em Portugal se encontra este uso [nesta revista de 1861](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1L7_uP-EcKgC&pg=RA2-PA43&dq=palpite&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgv288o3dAhUMY6wKHZGWDkkQ6AEIrwEwFA#v=onepage&q=palpite&f=false) e em 1865 numa obra de Camilo de Castelo Branco:

> —É muita delicadeza da parte de v. ex.ª, disse Iphigenia.
> —Oh, minha senhora!... tartamudeou o morgado da Agra, offerencendo-lhe o braço.
> —Parece, tornou ella quando iam subindo, que **o meu palpite não me enganou**…
> —O palpite de v. ex.ª
> —Sim… eu contava com um cavalheiro no rigor da palavra… Delicadeza egual ao talento, qualidades que raras vezes se conformam.
> [Camillo Castelo Branco, *A queda d’um anjo*, [1º edição 1865], Lisboa, 1873, p. 204.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=TMUNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA204&dq=palpite&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgv288o3dAhUMY6wKHZGWDkkQ6AEIjgEwDw#v=onepage&q=palpite&f=false)

Comment: Mercenáaario! haha, é bom ver-te de volta, a ti e à tua qualidade costumeira <3

Comment: @ANeves, mercenário nada, eu já tinha a resposta pronta (no word) quando vi a tua bounty. Quando é que a lançaste? Não pode ter sido muito antes de eu postar a resposta. Também te precipitaste um bocado. A pergunta não estava cá assim há tanto tempo.

Comment: Dia 27, às 19:43 (faz hover com o rato por cima do "in 6 days" do bounty). E tu respondeste  dia 27 às 20:35. :) Lancei-a porque vi esta pergunta com 3 dias e, tendo achado que a qualidade dela está bem acima da média, resolvi lançar o bounty para *incitar as urbes*...

Comment: Se sacrificar 50 pontos der respostas destas, ó, acho que abro um par de bounties por semana. ;)

Comment: @ANeves, Obrigado pelo elogio. Mas então tás a ver, postei a resposta 52 minutos depois de teres lançado a bounty. Achas que eu vasculho o Google Books e escrevo a resposta em 52 minutos? (Se calhar achas, mas tenta tu fazê-lo, e vais ver o tempo que demora ;) ) Ah, e só para encontrar o raio da 7ª edição do Moraes Silva (a primeira onde vem o *palpite* ) foi um castigo.

Comment: _Não haveis de ser vós o que haveis de jogar_ — interessante, diria _não haveis de ser vós **que** haveis de jogar_ ou _não haveis de ser vós o [=aquele] que há de jogar_

Comment: @Artefacto, é, é estranho. Não sei se seria sintaxe comum naquele tempo ou se terá sido engano.